# Addition of two numbers, twist is that the length of number can be very large

Tags: java, c, swift

Today I had an interview and the interviewer asked to make a program for addition of two numbers, I get shocked how can he give a simple question but the question is different

> the length of two number can be anything (10,20,30 or even 1000 etc.)

- if you convert it to int,double,long double if the number is greater than their range than the answer can be wrong.

Please help me for the question.

Comment: Than please provide the link.

Comment: you can find heaps of duplicates in the tag [tag:bigint]

Comment: Infinite length numbers?  According to [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_characterizations#1968.2C_1973_Knuth.27s_characterization) "An algorithm must always terminate after a finite number of steps," so there can be no such algorithm.  What kind of a silly person would ask you to write a program for which there is no valid algorithm?  Are you sure they didn't ask for how to add numbers of arbitrary but finite length?

Comment: Its interview question I can't say simply a+b = answer

Answer (score 1):

You can always take the two numbers in arrays (i.e. arrays have digits of the numbers as elements) and add them as we add manually i.e. start from one's digit and store the carry if it's present then do the same for ten's digit, then hundred's digit and so on.

Say you want to add 123 and 329.

```
X = 123, X[] = [1,2,3]
Y = 329, Y[] = [3,2,9]
```

You start with one's digit (the rightmost or last element) and add the elements of both X and Y arrays and add carry to it (initially set to 0). If the addition comes out to be greater than 10, set `carry = sum / 10` (since we are adding each element, this carry shall always be either 0 or 1) and the addition to `add [i] = sum % 10`. Repeat till all the elements of smaller array are over. Then add the carry to remaining elements of larger array continuing the above logic.

```
carry = 0
Step 1 : 3 + 9 + carry (0) = 5, carry => 12 / 10 = 1, add => 12 % 10 = 2
Step 2 : 2 + 2 + carry (2) = 6, carry => 6 / 10 = 0, add => 6 % 10 = 6
Step 3 : 3 + 1 + carry (0) = 4, carry => 4 / 10 = 0, add => 4 % 10 = 4
```

Ans = 462

Obviously the array storing sum may have one digit extra so take care of that as well.

Comment: But if we store the carry how we recognize this carry is of which index.

Comment: You need only one carry and set it to zero or one after adding each corresponsing digit.

Comment: @JeeVanTiWari Added an example in the answer. Should be easy to convert into code.

Comment: How do you propose storing an infinite length number in an array?

Comment: @pjs you dynamically allocate the arrays. Use `realloc`. As long as there is memory in the system, you should be fine.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Dynamic allocation won't help with infinite lengths.